# " characters not properly escaped in MVC.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am very noob at razor.

A razor page runs this JQuery intruction:

```
var myVar = "@Html.Raw(ViemModel.Name)";
```

It runs fine until I pass a view model whose Name includes some double quotes:
name = blabla"blou"bla

Then, at runtime, the compiler breaks into the corresponding file of my razor file class inside the script documents node ( = top node when you debug an MVC app).
At this stage, I can see that
@Html.Raw(ViemModel.Name) has been converted to blabla"blou"bla.
So the line into the file displays:

```
var myVar = "blabla"blou"bla";
```

So the quotes are not excaped causing the exception.

I don't know at all how does this  script documents node work and how to work my instruction so that it does not mess with it.

I can have the code to work if I use :

```
 var myVar = "@data.NomEntite".replace("&quot;", "\"").replace("&quot;", "\"");
```

But it is obviously not an option as the code would misbehave if the valuethenindludes accent characters or simple quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Html.Raw dumps out the string as is without escaping the html.

You could try:

```
var myVar = "@Html.Raw(Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(ViewModel.Name)";
```

Comment: If I do that, the " is changed to &quot;
So it s apparently similar to not using @Html.Raw

Comment: What about if you use JsonConvert.Serialize(ViewModel.Name)? You'll have to add the NewtonSoft nuget package.

Comment: Or @Html.Raw(Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(ViewModel.Name)?

Comment: Silly me! :)
 @Html.Raw(Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(ViewModel.Name)
dos work like a charm. Thx a ton Mike. :)

Comment: want to put it as a proper answer so I can flag it appropriately rather than a comment flag?